# importing a .sql db dump postgres 11, pgadmin 4

Tags: postgresql, psql, database-dump

I have a SQL dump file: `C:\Users\Rayyan\Desktop\dump_2.sql`.

I have been trying to import this for so long. I am using pgadmin 4, and since I could find nothing in that gui to help, I tried using psql console (I'm on windows).

So I created my new database "wecudos" in pgadmin4.

Then tried the following command in psql console:

```
psql wecudos < C:\Users\Rayyan\Desktop\dump_2.sql
```

according to the specified format:

```
psql dbname < dumpfile
```

This is not working, please help, I have also added a screenshot of the error/data I entered, thanks!

[image]

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Hi, I have added a screenshot showing the error, please help, thanks

Comment: Please open a `cmd.exe` **manually** then call `psql` from there. Do not use the shortcut provided by the Windows installer - that shortcut is not suitable for this kind of tasks.

Comment: Hi, i am getting this error : 'psql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=windows+%22is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command%2C%22&t=h_&ia=web

Comment: Is this because i have not changed any environment variables? thats partly because i dont know how to do that :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184318/discussion-between-ray92-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Comment: Hi i changed the env variables, and now im getting a different type of error , whose screenshot ive posted, please help , thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on the Tools tab in the top > Query Tool.
Then click on the folder icon in the Query Editor area > then select the location of the SQL file.